# Finding probability density function $W=|Y-X|$.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X,Y$ are independent random variables and have density function $U(0,1)$, how can calculate probability density function of $W=|Y-X|\,, 0<w<1$.

Comment: New spat of 4 questions in roughly 6 hours, to which, unfortunately, the following question still fully applies: "What about your numerous previous questions, where people commented, asked you for explanations or for personal input? Are you going to leave them in disarray? And about the present question, why are you continuing to flatly post your homework here, item after item, systematically flouting the rules of the site? This is rather apalling, no?"

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1681363/321264

Answer (score 2):

For $0<w<1,$

The DF of $W$ is 
$$\begin{align}F_W(w) &= P[W \le w] \\&=P[|Y-X|\le  w]\\&=P[-w \le Y-X \le w] \\&=P[(X,Y)\in A]\end{align}$$ where $$\begin{align}A &=\{ (x,y):-w \le y-x \le w\} \\&=\text{Area of A} \\ &=1-(1-w)^2\end{align}$$.

Hence $$F_W(w)= \begin{cases} 0, & w\le0 \\ 1-(1-w)^2,& 0<w<1 \\ 1, &w\ge1\end{cases}$$

Hence you can find the pdf.