# Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, uniformly distributed in the interval $[0, 1]$. Find the CDF and the PDF of $|X − Y|$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So  this what I have: 
\begin{align}
\ F_{z}(Z) &= P (Z<z) \\\
\    &= P( |X-Y| < z)\\
\    &= P(-z < X-Y < z) \\
\    &= P(-z+y<X<z+y)\\
\    &=F_x(z+y)-F_{x}(-z+y) = ?
\end{align}

As for the pdf it is just:

\begin{align}
f_{z}(Z)=f_{x}(z+y)+f_{x}(-z+y)
\end{align}

Comment: Duplicate of [CDF of absolute value of difference in random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681363/cdf-of-absolute-value-of-difference-in-random-variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the unit square $\Omega = [0,1]^2$.  $|X-Y|$ is directly proportional to the distance from the diagonal from the diagonal $X = Y$.  The event $\{|X - Y| \le z\}$ is represented by the red region. For all $d \in [0,1]$,

The CDF is the area of the $\color{red}{\text{red region}}$.
$$F_Z(d) = P(\color{red}{|X - Y| \le d}) = 1 - (1-d)^2 = 2d - d^2$$

Differentiating the CDF with respect to $d$ on $(0,1)$ gives the PDF.
$$f_Z(d) = F_Z'(d) = 2 - 2d.$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.