# How to find $P\left(\sqrt{(X_2 - X_1)^2 + (Y_2 - Y_1)^2} > X_2 + X_1\right)$ where $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ are uniformly distributed from [0,5]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

How to find $P((X_2 - X_1)^2 + (Y_2 - Y_1)^2 > X_2 + X_1)$ where $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2 \sim U[0,5]$ and iid.

Rearranging the probability, we have:

$$P\left(\sqrt{(X_2 - X_1)^2 + (Y_2 - Y_1)^2} > X_2 + X_1\right) = P((Y_2 - Y_1)^2) > (X_2 + X_1)^2 - (X_2 - X_1)^2 )$$

Then letting $T=Y_2 - Y_1,U=X_2+X_1,V=X_2-X_1$, we have:

$$ P((Y_2 - Y_1)^2 > X_2 + X_1 - (X_2 - X_1)^2 ) = P(T^2 > U^2 - V^2 ) $$

where

$$
f(t)= \begin{cases}t+5 & \text { for } -5<t<5 \\ 5-t & \text { for } 0 \leq t<5 \\ 0 & \text { otherwise. }\end{cases}
$$

$$
f(u)= \begin{cases}u & \text { for } 0<u<5 \\ 5-u & \text { for } 5 \leq u<10 \\ 0 & \text { otherwise. }\end{cases}
$$

$$
f(v)= \begin{cases}v+5 & \text { for } -5<v<5 \\ 5-v & \text { for } 0 \leq v<5 \\ 0 & \text { otherwise. }\end{cases}
$$

But I am stuck here, I am not sure what the joint distribution would be. Further, I am not sure how the marginal would be written out since we have $U^2 - V^2$ on the RHS instead of 1 variable…

Do we have to make a new variable i.e. $Z = U^2 - V^2$?

$$P(T^2 > Z) = \int_0^5 \int_0^z f(t,z)dtdz$$

I am not sure where to go from here

Comment: I answered the same problem here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4856444/1231520

some days ago!!!

Comment: In view of the striking similarity with the linked question, please let us know the context that led you to consider this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring the inequality and rearranging yields $\left(Y_2-Y_1\right)^2\gt4X_1X_2$. By separately considering $\frac15(X_1,X_2)$ and $\frac15(Y_1,Y_2)$ on the unit square and determining the relevant areas, you can obtain $P(4X_1X_2\gt a)=P(X_1X_2\gt\frac a4)=1+\frac a{100}\left(\log\left(\frac a{100}\right)-1\right)$ (the area above the hyperbola) and $P((Y_2-Y_1)^2\gt a)=P(|Y_2-Y_1|\gt \sqrt a)=\left(1-\frac{\sqrt a}5\right)^2$ (the area of two right iscosceles triangles).

The desired probability is

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^{25}P(4X_1X_2\le a)\frac{\partial P((Y_2-Y_1)^2\le a)}{\partial a}\,\mathrm da
&=&
-\int_0^{25}\frac a{100}\left(1-\log\left(\frac a{100}\right)\right)\frac\partial{\partial a}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt a}5\right)^2\,\mathrm da
\\
&=&
\int_0^{25}\frac a{100}\left(1-\log\left(\frac a{100}\right)\right)\frac1{5\sqrt a}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt a}5\right)\,\mathrm da
\\
&=&
\frac1{2500}\int_0^{25}\left(1-\log\left(\frac a{100}\right)\right)\left(5\sqrt a-a\right)\,\mathrm da
\\
&=&
\frac1{144}\left(13+12\log2\right)
\\[4pt]
&\approx&
0.148\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

[Here’s Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/4dd7f405bf4b7967c026f335350e8cf1) that checks the result by simulation.

Comment: You may note that it is a duplicate question. Some days ago, using a similar method, I answered the same problem here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4856444/1231520

Comment: @Amir: Thanks for the pointer; I hadn't seen that question and answer. Strictly speaking it's not a duplicate question, since the OP doesn't seem to have been aware that the present problem can be reformulated in this manner, but certainly it would have been enough to link to your solution of the reformulated problem.

Comment: I guess it is an exam question, asked by two different persons within a few days. I am new here, and do not how such cases are managed. You are a very senior member and you may look into this case.

Comment: @Amir: I left comments under the two questions asking the OPs to provide the context that led them to consider this problem.

Comment: Nice action! Thank you!

Comment: @joriki, not an exam question, but for Jane Streets monthly problem.